# Display submit button when type in textarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area field and a submit button available on the form which is always visible. We have a requirement to display the submit button only when user start typing in text area field and it contains value.
So that user cannot submit the empty form. Can anyone pls suggest some JavaScript/JQuery piece of code for this task?

Comment: please show some code you have tried.

Comment: Dear Everyone, I would like to thank everyone who shown their interest in this post. My question is answered and I am happy with the support received in this thread :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty straight forward, just hide the button and use a keyup event handler to show it again when the textarea has a value

```
$('#button').hide();

$('#textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length) {
        $('#button').show();
    }else{
        $('#button').hide();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDk8f/)

**EDIT**

or as requested, whithout jQuery

```
var button  = document.getElementById('button'),
    txtarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

button.style.display = 'none';

txtarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length) {
        button.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        button.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDk8f/1/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it works perfect.Is it possible to achieve this task with JavaScript code instead of jQuery?

Comment: @user1934643 - sure it's possible, added something for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Set disabled

```
$("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

On Change

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    var validated = true;
    if($('#nome').val().length === 0) validated = false;   
    if(validated) $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: One has to wonder why the only wrong answer is upvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=submit]').hide();

function checkValue(element){
    if($(element).val() !=== '') {
         $('input[type=submit]').show();
    } else {
         $('input[type=submit]').hide();
    }
}

$('input[type=text]).on('keyup', function() {
    checkValue(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<button id="btn" onclick="alert('submit');" style="display:none">Btn</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#ta').keyup(function(){       
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        $('#btn').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#btn').hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9VxBC/)